# Anchor tag click not working but opening in new tab works

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Now on browser when I click on this anchor tag the url doesn't open but when I hover on it the url is displayed in bottom left corner of the screen and also if i try to open in new tab by right click it works.

Any idea how can I make it work such that when I click on it the form will open in new tab?

```js
$('#mydiv').append('<p>Please use <a href= https://docs.google.com/forms/' id="open-url" target="_blank">this google form</a>.</p>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='mydiv'>
</div>
```

Comment: You missing href property double quote

Comment: href= https://docs.google.com/forms/' into href= "https://docs.google.com/forms/"

Comment: Your code, basically, is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: `'<p>Please use <a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/" id="open-url" target="_blank">this google form</a>.</p>'`

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: See the snippet I made does not even run

Answer (score 1):

Small syntax error in the referring link. You have to add double quotation to the link provided.

I found a good source where you can learn about how to append anchor tag to html 
body
http://jqueryexamplecode.blogspot.com/2012/12/how-to-append-anchor-tag-to-html-body.html

```js
$('#mydiv').append('<p>Please use <a href=" https://docs.google.com/forms/" id="open-url" target="_blank">this google form</a>.</p>')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id='mydiv'>
</div>
```